# iFrame + PDF.js + puppeteer - good combination to generate and show PDF files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, iframe

since monday i try to find the right way of fast and secure generating and displaying PDF Files with the following - maybe im just confused or to blind to see the answer:

Apache - runs my PHP Scripts for my actual project (port 443)
NodeJS - runs a single script for generating PDF files from HTML (port 8080)

What i need: Ensure, that the User is allowed to generate and view the PDF.
It is important to me to have the viewer bar (as seen in the screenshot) is available.

There is a cookie in which a Session-Hash is stored and on which the user authenticates whith on every request (for example via AJAX).

Description of the full procedure:
On one page of my project an iFrame is displayed. In this is a PDF-viewer (from PDF.js) is loaded and some buttons around it:
[state before it all begins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SghMt.png)

Clicking on a button on the left (named with "Load PDF 1", ...) fires the following Event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".reportelement", function () {
    //some data needs to be passed
    let data = "report=birthdaylist";

     //point iFrame to a new address
     $("#pdfViewer").attr("src", "https://example.org/inc/javascript/web/viewer.html?file=https://example.org:8080?" + data);
});
```

At this point, the iFrame is going to reload the viewer, which takes the GET argument and executes it:

```
https://example.org/inc/javascript/web/viewer.html?file=https://example.org:8080?" + data //sends the data to the NodeJS script and recieves PDF

==> ?file=https://example.org:8080 //GET... it's bad... How to do a POST in iFrame?!
```

So, have a look at the NodeJS Script (I have to say I am not very famliar with async and NodeJS):

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = require("url");
var qs = require('querystring');
const request = require("request-promise");

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem", "utf-8"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem", "utf-8"),
    passphrase: 'XXXXXXXX'
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

    (async function () {

        if (req.method == 'POST') {

            var body = '';

            req.on('data', function (data) {
                body += data;

                // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
                // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
                if (body.length > 1e6)
                    req.connection.destroy();
            });

            req.on('end', function () {

                //got a selfsigned certificate only, will change it soon!
                process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0

                (async function () {

                    var result = await request.post('https://example.org/index.php', {

                            //htpasswd secured at the moment
                            'auth': {
                                'user': 'user',
                                'pass': 'pass',
                                'sendImmediately': false
                            },

                            //i would like to send the cookie oder the hash in it
                            //or something else to it ensure, that the user is allowed to
                            form: {
                                giveme: 'html'
                            }
                        },
                        function (error, response, body) {

                            //for debugging reasons
                            console.log("error: " + error);
                            console.log("response: " + response);
                            console.log("body: " + body);

                        }
                    );

                    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

                    const main = async () => {
                        //generating pdf using result from request.post                            
                    }

                    const rendered_pdf = await main();

                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=mypdf.pdf',
                        'Content-Length': rendered_pdf.length
                    });

                    res.end(rendered_pdf);

                })();
            });

        } else if (req.method == 'GET') {
            console.log("we got a GET");
        } else {
            console.log("we got NOTHING");
        }

    })();

}).listen(8080);
```

Everything is working fine and PDF's are displayed well - but as i mentioned before, i dont know how to ensure, that the user is allowed to generate and see the PDF.

**tldr;**

Is there a way (maybe without an iFrame) to secure the user is permitted? It is important to me to have the viewer bar (as seen in the screenshot) is available.

[diagram of current procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPbWz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution.

[diagram of new approach/token logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfrw8.png)

Using a Token (hash or random string) for retrieving a PDF file only should do it.

The Token does not authenticate the user. I think this is an safer approach?

Feel free to comment/answer :)